# Get Generated RQL for a RavenDB Query

Tags: ravendb

Is it possible to get the generated RQL including parameters and everything?
If you call .ToString() it gives the command with placeholders for the parameters (e.g. $p0, $p1, ... $p17). That makes it annoying when trying to debug.